# Snowflake SQL compilation error: syntax error line XX at position XX unexpected '('

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While running SQL query on Snowflake, I am getting syntax error that I have *unexpected '('*. Below is the code that is giving me the error.

```
,(EndOrder_time) - min(StartOrder_time) over (
    partition by EntryNumber, TechnicianEnterpriseID
    order by RouteDateTime rows between 1 preceding and current row
) day (4) to second as Repair_Time
```

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake calculates timestamp diffs in this way:

[`DATEDIFF(SECONDS, StartOrder_time, EndOrder_time)`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html)

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake added the ability to use the + and - for date math in November.  "day (4) to second" is not Snowflake syntax

Comment: I saw the announcement (and docs) some time ago, but you can't get seconds out of it. And I've only been able to make it work with `DATE`, not with `TIMESTAMP` (type error).  Probably my bad.

Comment: Good catch.  I read the release notes and documentation and it doesn't look like timestamps are supported.

Comment: Actually, the docs say "date_or_time_expr1, date_or_time_expr2 must be a date, a time, a timestamp, or an expression that can be evaluated to a date, a time, or a timestamp. The value date_or_time_expr1 is subtracted from date_or_time_expr2."  but I can't get it to work with `TIMESTAMP`...